# Where do I find connection string to TFS database in Android Studio?

Tags: database, android-studio, web-config

Brand new to Android Studio.  I inherited a project with no documentation and very little communication with the developer who handed the app off to me.

I have a .db file that I could open in SQLite browser and I have a another db file named tfs (with no file extension) that I am having a hard time opening to view the data.

I got a short response back from the develop to look in the "config" in Android Studio for connection string to be able to view data in this tfs file.

Am I misunderstanding him? or is there a config file in Android Studio for the app where I can get the information to db that I seek?

Comment: I don't know what that "tfs" database file is, but it's not something from Microsoft Team Foundation Server. You'll be better served having a more in-depth conversation with the original project owner.

Comment: There is just a file named tfs.   Is there a tfs database?  Apparantly the data is in this file.

Comment: TFS has a database, but it's nothing that would be part of a project, and it's a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Comment: ok thanks.  Believe me, all my problems would be solved if could get original developer to contact me back.